# Stake pool blockchain sync is incredibly slow

Tags: stake-pool, cardano-db-sync, spo

Has anyone synced a node lately? It has been 3 days and I've only reached 75% of the tip. This is much slower than a few months ago. I'm currently only connected to the IOHK North America relay with a valency of 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected, depending on your hardware, mostly CPU and disk speed, it can take some time.

Cardano mainnet launched about 4 years ago, but just in the last 3 months, the storage taken by the db synced chain has doubled from 30G to 60G.